# Uniqueness of a Polynomial Evaluated at $\pi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Short question, yet interesting (I think). Suppose $a$ and $b$ are each polynomials with *integer* coefficients. Let's use the notation $a[x]$ to denote the "number" which results from evaluating a polynomial at $x$. (see definition 7.6.1 of [this excellent resource](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19s/notes.pdf)). Is it possible that $a \neq b$ as polynomials while
$$
a[\pi] = b[\pi]?
$$

For context, I'm an undergrad and my knowledge of abstract algebra reaches approximately up to, but does *not* include, the theory of field extensions. Thank you all.

EDIT: Wow, thank you for the quick response. I guess I might as well add: is this also true when $a$ and $b$ are rational functions? For that matter, are two rational functions considered equal if their numerators are each the zero polynomial while the denominators are distinct?

I suspect that we still have $a[\pi] = b[\pi]\implies a = b$, since (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Definitions)) the set of rational functions is defined in terms of equivalences classes, like rational numbers, is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, it would extend to rational functions for the same reasons.

Comment: Although algebraic numbers are defined for polynomials with integer coefficients, that is equivalent to polynomials with rational coefficients and rational functions.  for $f(x)=\frac {p(x)}{q(x)}$ then $f(w) = 0$ is a root and $w$ is algebraic if and only if $p(w) = 0$ and that is true if and only if $P(x) = p(x)\times$(lowest common multiple of the denominators of the coefficents of $p(x)$)  has a root $P(w)=0$; and $P(w)$ will be a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Of course if you allow for *irrational* coefficients this will not be true at all.  (As any polynomial with $x-\pi$ as a factor will be equal to zero if evaluation for $\pi$.)

Comment: Thanks, I honestly really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would imply

$$(a-b)[\pi]=0,$$

making $\pi$ an algebraic number, which is know to be [false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) by the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Both answers are absolutely right... and well known in mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 7):

No, $a(x) - b(x) $ is a polynomial with integer coefficients with $\pi$ as it's root which would mean $\pi$ is algebraic contradiction (except if $a(x) \equiv b(x) $)